# Put Dynamically Generated GridView to Specific <div> in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created gridview in code behind file of C#.

I want to place that gridview into a specific `<div>` of source file.

My code to generate the grid is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class gv1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds;
    SqlDataAdapter da;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AMIR-PC\\MOHEMMAD;Initial Catalog=CRM_InvestPlus;Integrated Security=True");

   }
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       cn.Open();
       string query = "select V.Version_Name,S.Software_Name,C.Capacity,V.Price from " +
        "Software_Master S inner join Version_Master V inner join Dealer_License_Capacity C " +
        "on V.Version_ID=C.Version_ID and V.Software_ID=C.Software_ID on " +
        "S.Software_ID=C.Software_ID where C.ID='D00001' and C.Software_ID='001' and C.Version_ID='1'";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();

    GridView gr1 = new GridView();
    Table t = new Table();
    gr1.Controls.Add(t);



    int count = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Capacity"].ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(i, i, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();


        TextBox txtPrice = new TextBox();

        FileUpload fl = new FileUpload();
        fl.ID = "fl" + i;


        if (i == 0)
        {
            cell1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Software_Name"].ToString();
            cell2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Version_Name"].ToString();
            //cell3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
            cell3.Controls.Add(txtPrice);
        }
        else
        {
            cell1.Text = "";
            cell2.Text = "";
            cell3.Text = "";
        }



        cell4.Controls.Add(fl);

        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        row.Cells.Add(cell3);
        row.Cells.Add(cell4);

        gr1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(i, row);



    }
    form1.Controls.Add(gr1);
   }
}
```

Grid is generated successfully...

Now I want to place the grid gr1 to `<div class="block-border">` tag that is:

```
 <div class="grid_6">   
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="block-border">
```

How is it possible to place gr1 in last most `<div>`..???

Please help
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add runat="server" and an id to your div tag and you can do it like this

```
<div id="block" runat="server" class="block-border">

block.Controls.Add(gr1);
```

Comment: sorry block is accessible but only `class="block-border"` <div> should be given the id or all <div>s should be placed id..?? @COLD TOLD