# Adding dynamic content to a jQueryUI Accordion

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

There are a couple of questions here, but they seem to be old and make reference to upcoming functionality, so I'm wondering if this has been done since those questions were asked.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Category                         Provision
1   Plan Highlights                  Annual Maximum
2   Plan Highlights                  Lifetime Maximum
16  Benefits - Preventive            Routine Preventive Care - Child
17  Benefits - Preventive            Routine Preventive Care - Adult
18  Benefits - Preventive            Immunizations - Child
22  Benefits - Physician Services    Primary Care Physican (PCP) Office Visit
23  Benefits - Physician Services    Specialty Care Physican Office Visit
24  Benefits - Physician Services    Surgery Performed in Physician's Office
```

What I'd like to do is create an accordion with Category as the header, and then on each accordion tab I want to place a gridview with a list of all Provisions assigned to that category.  The problem is, the Categories will change based on a user's selection, and the Provisions will also change based on the same selection.

If it matters, I'm using a SQL Server back end.

So, I'm trying to figure out if I can add each accordion title dynamically (pulling the names from a "Select DISTINCT Category" query), add a gridview to the accordion panel and fill the gridview (again using a "Select DISTINCT Provision" query as the data source).  Is there some functionality built in to an accordion to handle this?  If not, is there some place to find sample code to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about an accordion, except classes that are added to the elements so it can be manipulated.  This is the minimum markup required to create a working accordion:

```
<div id="myAccordion">
    <h3 id="myHeader1">Header 1</h3>
    <div>Stuff</div>
    <h3 id="myHeader2">Header 2</h3>
    <div>More Stuff</div>
</div>
```

and the minimum jQuery:

```
$('#myAccordion').accordion();
```

To dynamically append a header is simple:

```
$('#myAccordion')
.append('<h3 id="myHeader3">Header 3</h3><div>Still More Stuff</div>')
.accordion();
```

As for your "gridview": Whatever kind of gridview you're working with, if your result is an HTML table, you just need to and append it to the `div` below the `h3`, in similar fashion to the example I've given you for the header, and recall the `accordion()` function.

If you are working with the ASP.Net GridView as your tag suggests, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766488/put-dynamically-generated-gridview-to-specific-div-in-asp-net-c-sharp) post will probably give you what you need to get to this point.